# How to replace a 'value' on mysqli_fetch_array when printing out search results?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the confusing title. I am as confused.

SO what I am trying to do is print results from the MySQL database I've got. I have a checkbox value as "yes" in my DB and I would like to replace this to some other word while printing out the results.

I've tried different ways but all of them break the page, because I'm new to this and have no idea what I am doing.

Here is my code so far (only put what I think is relevant):

```
$keyword= "";
if (isset($_POST["keyword"])) {
    $keyword = ($_POST["keyword"]);
}

$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pcdata WHERE name LIKE '$keyword' LIMIT 0, 25");

if (!$results) {
    echo "Not found...";
} else {
    echo "Found...<br>";
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "Model: " . $row['model'] . "<br>";
    echo "Operating system: " . $row['model'] . "<br>";
    echo "Type of computer: " . $row['pctype'] . "<br>";
    echo "Other information: " . $row['info'] . "<br>";
    echo "Need help ASAP: " . $row['help'] . "<br>";                    
}
```

Comment: You mean `echo "Need help ASAP: " . ( $row['help'] !== 'yes' ? $row['help'] : 'other word' ) . "<br>";  `?

Comment: Or `if ($row['help'] === 'yes') $row['help'] = 'other word';`

Comment: [See the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers! The if construct is perfect, now I don't even end up with a empty result if the box is unticked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$keyword= "";
    if (isset($_POST["keyword"]))
    $keyword=($_POST["keyword"]);
$results=mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT * 
FROM pcdata 
WHERE name LIKE '$keyword' LIMIT 0,25");

    if (!$results)  {
        echo "Not found...";
            }
    else    {
        echo "Found...<br>";
        }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
            echo "Model: " . $row['model'] . "<br>";
            echo "Operating system: " . $row['model'] . "<br>";
            echo "Type of computer: " . $row['pctype'] . "<br>";
            echo "Other information: " . $row['info'] . "<br>";
            echo "Need help ASAP: ";
            if ($row['help'] === 'yes'){
                echo 'YES';
            } else {
                echo 'NO';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

We check the value of `$row['help']` and if it "yes" printing 'YES', if other - printing 'NO'

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try a simple *if* inside your while:

```
$myvariable='';
    if($row['help']='yes'){
        $myvariable='put_something_here';
    }
```

And in your echo just do:

```
 echo "Need help ASAP: " . $myvariable . "<br>";
```

Or a ternary solution:

```
$row['help'] == 'yes' ? 'put_something_here' : 'what_do_you_want_to_print_if_it_is_not_yes'
```

Comment: This actually prints the given value no matter what the original value is. I didn't explain so good that I had inserted data from a html checkbox. So database got "" if unticked and "yes" if ticked. But I did get an answer to this from another person - thank you anyway! : )

Comment: You could add an else statement in my first example or in the second example in the ternary solution i provided in the second part in _what_do_you_want_to_print_if_it_is_not_yes_  you could add the value you wanted to be printed. It would work for both of them.

Comment: Funnily enough I couldn't make either of them work. But yeah.. you don't need to try to explain it to me.. it might take a while. :')

Answer (score 0):

you can also use select statement combined with Case statement which will result as desired try following code

```
$keyword= "";

if (isset($_POST["keyword"])) 
{
  $keyword = ($_POST["keyword"]);

}
//used different variable to build query

$selectquery="SELECT id,name,model,pctype,info CASE WHEN help='yes' THEN 'Your Yes String' WHEN help='no' THEN 'Your No String' else 'nothing' END as help FROM pcdata where name like '$keyword'" ;
//passed $selectquery to mysqli_qery
$results = mysqli_query($con, $selectquery);

if (!$results) {
 echo "Not found...";
} else {
echo "Found...<br>";
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<br>";
echo "Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Model: " . $row['model'] . "<br>";
echo "Operating system: " . $row['model'] . "<br>";
echo "Type of computer: " . $row['pctype'] . "<br>";
echo "Other information: " . $row['info'] . "<br>";
echo "Need help ASAP: " . $row['help'] . "<br>";                    
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this works too! Even though it seemed a bit daunting at first.. :)